# Execution order of different CDI Events in same transaction

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

In my software solution i use JavaEE with EJBs. On certain events i fire different events regarding what happend in the system. In my specific case i fire two different events that should be executed after the transaction finished successfully.

As far as i know the order of execution of the same event is not specified but how does CDI execute the events when they are different types and fired one after the other?

So in my code i do fire(Event) and then in the same transaction fire(Event). Is Event executed before Event? Researched this but i could not find an answer.

Here it is stated that the execution order of the same event is not a given but there is nothing about different events: http://www.next-presso.com/2014/06/you-think-you-know-everything-about-cdi-events-think-again/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until CDI 1.2 (check [here](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr346/index.html), chapter 10.5):

> The order in which observer methods are called [after firing an event] is not defined, and so portable applications **should not rely upon the order in which observers are called**.

In fact, the CDI container may enqueue your fired events in a given list, specially when you marked observer as a transactional observer method. The implementation list may be ordered (FIFO or any other), but you have no guarantee of it.

Since CDI 2.0 (check [here](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=365), Chapter 10.5.2), you may define an order using the @Priority annotation and specifying a number as its value. Observers with smaller priority values are called first and observers with no @Priority annotation gets de default priority (Priority.APPLICATION + 500). As with CDI 1.2, observers with same priority does not have any previously defined order and may be called by CDI container in any order.

CDI 2.0 observer ordering **does not apply to asynchronous observer methods** (per spec), as it's expected that observer methods get called as soon as it is possible and in different contexts. If you need some kind of ordering in you use case, you should make your asynchronous observer trigger the next event, instead of calling it from your "main" method.

Comment: So even if i fire Two different Event-Objects the order is not specified?

Comment: Yes. Unless you are using CDI 2 and defining different priorities, the order is unspecified. You must realize that you may "discover" the order of a given implementation in such cases, but it is not recommended to rely on it because a future version of the same implementation may change it without colliding with the spec.